# Admin menu in front-end

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, front-end

How to move an admin menu from backend to front-end ?

Menu is create with  `add_menu_page($menu_slug)` and the URL is like `abc.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=$menu_slug`.

I need to use the admin page on the front-end like `abc.com/$menu_slug/`

Comment: This sounds like a large request, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I try to call the view, and the controller from php template but it's not working.

Comment: @FredG Where do you want the admin menu to be listed in the front end? In the menu navigation?

Comment: I just want to be able to call it front end instead of backend, so any solution is a good solution :)

Comment: @FredG You're gonna have to elaborate more on what you want exactly and what you're trying to achieve.